# How to setup Syslog-ng to relay received logs to ports on the same machine?

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

I was working on an architecture where we receive the logs from Syslog/rsyslog sources to a central syslog server. I have now three applications on the same server who also want to receive a copy of the logs. Is there a way I can do that with the configurations on the central server without the source syslogs sending it to multiple port?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Hi, you can configure syslog-ng to send logs to a specific network port using the network() or the syslog() destination, whichever you need. It does not matter if the destination server is actually on the same host.